# Safely send packet-like objects between threads, without inner synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, memory-barriers

Consider the following code, executed by thread A.

```java
MyPacket packet = new MyPacket();
modify(packet) // initialize some fields of the packet, change variables
//something needs to be done here to ensure that the initialization will be effectively done in the main memory before the reference is published
publishRef(packet) // publish the reference to the packet to other threads in some (thread safe)  way.
```

I don't want to use any synchronization / final fields in the MyPacket class because:

- packet and any object accessible from packet will never be used again in thread A after the publishRef line. (that's why I called it a "packet-like" object).
- it can be arbitrarily complex and can use non synchronized objects such as ArrayList.
- it would hurt performances of thread A.

How can i make sure that the initialization of packet in threadA has been properly flushed to the main memory before publishRef(packet) happens?

I've read that synchronization blocks do perform memory barriers, so does the following code work, and is it the right way to do it ? (it looks bad)

```java
MyPacket packet = new MyPacket();
modify(packet) // initialize some fields of the packet, change variables
synchronized(this) {};
publishRef(packet) // publish the reference to the packet to other threads in some (thread safe) way.
```

Or is there just a Thread.flushPendingWrites() method somewhere? (it would look better)

Or maybe there is nothing needed here because the publishRef(packet) method will inevitably encounter a memory barrier and flush pending writes somewhere because it needs to be threadsafe.

any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: It is your `publishRef` method who should bother about synchronization. Actually, when implementing given method, you will found that it is very difficult to avoid synchronization in it: "publish the reference to the packet to other threads in some (**thread safe**) way."

Comment: Ok, I currently use volatile variables in the publishRef method (but no synchronize keyword, only locks), so does the write/read operations on the volatile reference guaranty that any prior changes to the objects in thread A has been effectively transfered to the main memory and will be seen by the other threads?

Comment: In Java `volatile` provides all memory barriers needed for other thread to see the packet in completely modified state. There is no needs in additional `synchronize`.